passing along secret environment variables to called workflwo
I have a large docker setup with multiple repositories, nearly all of them have a nightly build. Except some minor differences (names, tags etc.) the build pipeline is the same.
To avoid duplication, I made a "master workflow".
the master workflow:
name: build and push to REDACTED

env:
  tag: "${{ github.run_id }}"

on:
  workflow_call:
   inputs: 
     # name of the image stored in REDACTED
     IMAGE_REPOSITORY:
       required: true
       type: string
       description: "Name of the image in REDACTED"
     DOCKERFILE_PATH:
       required: false
       type: string
       description: "path to the Dockerfile relative to the repository root"
       default: ""
     CONTEXT:
       required: false
       type: string
       description: "Context of the build e.g. all files mentionend in the Dockerfile are in src/"
       default: "." # current folder

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
    
      - name: Login to Docker Registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v3.2.0
        with:
          registry: "${{ secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY }}"
          username: "${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}"
          password: "${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}"

      - name: Setup Docker Buildx # used for caching
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3.4.0

      - name: Build and push image to container Registry (REDACTED)
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v6.4.0
        with:
          file: "${{ inputs.DOCKERFILE_PATH }}"
          context: "${{ inputs.CONTEXT }}"
          push: true
          tags: |
            "${{secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY}}/${{ inputs.IMAGE_REPOSITORY }}:${{ env.tag }}"
            "${{secrets.DOCKER_REGISTRY}}/${{ inputs.IMAGE_REPOSITORY }}:latest"
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha, mode=max

Now the Caller workflow:
name: "Build and push to Docker Registry"
on:
  # comment in when this should be run daily (or any other cron)
  schedule:
    - cron: "50 4 * * *" # runs every night a 4:50
  
  # comment in when the workflow should be triggered with commits to "main" or "master"
  push:
    branches: [ "main", "master" ]
    paths-ignore:
      - "REDACTED/**"
      - "REDACTED/**"
      - ".github/workflows/REDACTED.yml"
      - ".github/workflows/REDACTED.yml"
  
  # comment in when you need a manual trigger
  # workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    # repo permissions has to include reusable workflows under
    # repo -> settings -> actions -> General -> Actions permissions
    uses: REDACTED/REDACTED/.github/workflows/REDACTED.yml@main
    with:
      IMAGE_REPOSITORY: "REDACTED/REDACTED" # name of the image (e.g. REDACTED)
      CONTEXT: "./REDACTED" # mandatory when the sources are not in the repository root
    secrets: inherit
    # uses implicit the secrets DOCKER_REGISTRY, DOCKER_USERNAME, DOCKER_PASSWORD

I need to pass some secrets into my Dockerfile. Those secrets can be zero to many. I plan to inject those secrets via ENV SECRET=${SECRET} inside of the Dockerfile. For this, the secret has to be in the environment variables. Unfortunately, the environment variables set in the caller workflow won't get passed onto the called workflow. Additionally, you can't use the secrets-context when passing parameters (pass the env as a variable and then >> $GITHUB_ENV does not work). Also, I can't pass the environment variables as a secret, because I need to have secrets: inherit.
Is there any possibility to "copy" environment variables or other variables to the called workflow when I don't know the exact amount?
Thank you very much for any help :)

(Remember that anything in a Dockerfile can be easily extracted out; ENV variables can be shown in plain text with docker inspect.  You may not actually want to build these into your image.)
